# Define new properties and methods for object when it implements some interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In OOP, it's allowed to define new properties besides those which declared in interface which class implements:

```js
interface IIncapsuledData {
    propertyA: number;
    propertyB: string;
}

class TestClass implements IIncapsuledData {

    public constructor(private incapsuledData: IIncapsuledData) { }

    public get propertyA(): number { return this.incapsuledData.propertyA; }
    public get propertyB(): string { return this.incapsuledData.propertyB }

    // we can defined new getter without declaring new type alias or interface
    public get newComputedProperty(): string {
        return `${this.propertyA}__${this.propertyB}`;
    }
}
```

Can we do same for plain object?

```js
const objectWithoutClass: IIncapsuledData = {
    propertyA: 2,
    propertyB: 'b',
    // Error! Object literal may only specify known properties.
    get newComputedProperty(): string {
        return `${this.propertyA}__${this.propertyB}`;
    }
}
```

### Knows solutions

#### Declare new interface

```
interface IComputedData extends IIncapsuledData {
    readonly newComputedProperty: string;
}

const objectWithoutClass: IComputedData = {
    propertyA: 2,
    propertyB: 'b',
    get newComputedProperty(): string {
        return `${this.propertyA}__${this.propertyB}`;
    }
}
```

**Demerit**: unlike class case, me need to declare new interface. Routine work becomes more. Some elegant solution like in class case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an intersection type, and intersect with an indexer:

```
interface IEncapsuledData {
    propertyA: number;
    propertyB: string;
}

const objectWithoutClass: IEncapsuledData & { [key: string]: any } = {
  propertyA: 1,
  propertyB: '2',
  propertyC: 3
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So, it's most laconic what TypeScript allows...